# What does shadowOffset do in iOS exactly?

Tags: ios, ios7

I couldn't find this info anywhere so asking here.

What does `element.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)]` do exactly?

What offset does it indicate with respect to the element?

Comment: It sets the offset of the shadow, so how far the shadow goes out from the element.

Comment: @lafor, "is there any documentation available for the same?" is off-topic... and the OP didn't ask that so it shouldn't be added..

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The shadowOffset value changes the location of the shadow with respect to the element's frame.  An offset of (2,2) will put the shadow 2 pixels to the right and 2 pixels down with respect to the element.  An offset of (15,45) will put the shadow 15 pixels to the right and 45 pixels down.  These can also be negative values if you want the shadow to be to the top or left of the element.

And by pixels I mean units.  Based off the original (non-retina) pixel sizes of apple devices.

Comment: thank you, this made the most sense to me as a beginner

Comment: what if i want to add shadow at all four side?

Comment: Precise explanation! Thanks!

Comment: @Nimit the shadow defaults to being present on all four sides. ShadowOffset does what its name suggests, it offsets the shadow based on the input. For example, if you have a shadow radius of 10 and have an offset of (5, 5), the shadow will have a width of 5 on top/left and 15 on bottom/right.

Comment: So if what you say is true, and an offset of (2,2) will put the shadow 2 pixels to the right and 2 pixels down - why did apple use CGSize for that? for moving right and down - CGPoint make more sense no?

Answer (score 6):

Layers can have a shadow.  The layer's shadow uses several elements: `shadowOffset`, `shadowColor`, `shadowOpacity`, and `shadowRadius`.  Each element changes the respective appearance.

You can offset the shadow differently to change the direction the shadow is cast - how far from the layer and in which direction.  `shadowColor` will obviously change what color the shadow is (in case you don't want to use the default grayish color).  The `shadowOpacity` will adjust how opaque the shadow is.  The `shadowRadius` will adjust how large the shadow is.

`shadowOffset` takes in a CGSize. So you could for instance set your color for the shadow to green (just to make it visible) then set the offset like so:
`element.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)];`
This will set the shadow to appear to the bottom right. The Offset value can be anything you want, the first value in the CGSize is distance left/right (with negative being left, and positive being right), and second value is distance up/down (negative/positive respectively).

Comment: This is incorrect, positive offset values are down and to the right.

Comment: @ChrisConover That...is what I said?  "distance is left/right (with negative being left, and positive being right), and second value is distance up/down (negative/positive respectively)."

Comment: Then this was a typo: `then set the offset like so:
element.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)];
This will set the shadow to appear to the bottom left. `

Comment: Ah, you are indeed correct, I must have done a typo.  I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

ShadowOffset is a CGSize representing how far to offset the shadow from the path. The default value of this property is (0.0, -3.0).

Comment: Thanks for specifying the default. This is actually the part I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It effectively sets where the light that casts the shadow is. So it controls if the shadow is above / below, left / right. And by how much.

Answer (score -1):

Mmm... the Google tells me that it is listed in Apple's documentation for [CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html): [shadowOffset](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/shadowOffset)

```
shadowOffset

The offset (in points) of the layer’s shadow. Animatable.
@property CGSize shadowOffset
Discussion

The default value of this property is (0.0, -3.0).
Availability

    Available in iOS 3.2 and later.

Related Sample Code

    MTAudioProcessingTap Audio Processor

Declared In
CALayer.h
```